# Need help getting Ajax to work: jsonpCallback and php on the backend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a helluva time getting ajax calls and responses to work correctly in IE8 (yes, unfortunately, that's the version my workgroup is stuck on), Firefox, and Chrome.

I have the ajax requests going to a single PHP script on the backend.   Because I've experienced strange issues in the past where IE will suddenly complain / behave as if some of our internal/intranet servers are actually "cross-domain", I am making sure the PHP script wraps the data object into a callback function:

```
echo $callback_name.'('.$jsondata.');';
```

(However, all the ajax requests from the front-end are passing the same callback name, just to try to keep things simple:   jsonpCallback.)

My front-end requests all follow this same format:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'ajax_fetcher.php',
      data: { action: 'fetchexecmsg', incident_id: incident_id_number},
      dataType: 'jsonp', // doing this because it should avoid cross-domain issues
      jsonp:'callback_name',
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
      success: function(data){
          console.log("Ajax call to fetchexecmsg was successful.");
          Parse_JSON_object_into_Exec_Msg_Div(data);
      }
    });
```

I was doing most building / testing with Chrome.  So, today, I decided to test Firefox and IE8.
To my surprise, Firefox was complaining that 'jsonpCallback' wasn't an actual function ??

```
TypeError: jsonpCallback is not a function  (red text in the console)
```

My understanding was that if I had a "success" function already pre-defined, there'd be no need for that function to actually exist ?

So, I put that in globally as an empty function... and now Firefox is complaining:

```
Error: jsonpCallback was not called
```

and this is immediately followed by an ajax parseerror where jqXHR.responseText = undefined.
And I see now that Chrome is logging that parseerror -> undefined as well.

Can anybody provide any guidance on this?   I guess my focus right now should be on this 'jsonpCallback' thing.  I thought I needed that returned from the backend, so as to "fool" the browser into thinking it was getting Javascript and not data from some remote server.

And then, on the front-end side, I needed to set those jsonp and jsonpCallback variables in the ajax request.  But I THOUGHT an actual callback function, as defined with that jsonpCallback variable, was NOT necessary?

Thanks!

-= Dave =-

Comment: A related question I have... which may be part of root cause here... is...what should the PHP backend send back when there basically is no data?

Right now, I have it sending back "jsonpCallback();"

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I've gotten all three browsers to stop erroring for ONE of my ajax requests. (Hopefully, I'll be able to adjust the other requests and fix those as well.):    I removed the jsonpCallback function that I had actually written out in response to an error from one of the browsers.   I then adjusted my script on the backend so that, when there was no data, instead of sending back "jsonpCallback();" it would send a json_encoded array of $msg_object= array('status' => false);

Comment: Is there a reason you forcibly defined jSONPCallback's value? jQuery usually set it itself as to avoid conflicts within it's own code.
As can be readed from api.jquery.com/ajax:
_It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling_

Comment: Ahhhh.... I think I see what you're saying.  'jsonp' = the 'name' of the variable (for the jsonp callback function) that we want to pass in the GET or POST to the backend script.  I had assigned a value to 'jsonpCallback' thinking that I needed to manually assign that so that it would be passed to the backend.

And you're saying this doesn't, right?

That would make sense because I just saw something funky:  I put a line of code to dump out the object into one of my ajax calls.  And yet, when I'd execute the function, I'd sometimes see an object from some OTHER ajax request get printed!

Comment: Eric, you should post your response as an Answer, so I can give you credit.  Apparently, I can't give you credit for a "comment".   But removing my manual assignment of the 'jsonpCallback' key fixed my issues.   (No wonder I was confused by the fact that my stuff was working 25% of the time!)

Comment: Davey,thanks for the feedback. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave, remove the "jsonpCallBack" key from the options you setted for jQuery.Ajax.

As seen from http://api.jquery.com/ajax ,

> It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling.